# Calculate function: $\int_{a}^{b} \left(f{(x)}\right)dx=c$

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, functions, derivatives

Is there a way to find the function $f{(x)}$ for a given value of $a,b,c$?

$$\int_{a}^{b} \left(f{(x)}\right)dx=c$$

---

For example:

$a=0,b=1,c=\frac{1}{3}$ we get:

$$\int_{0}^{1} \left(f{(x)}\right)dx=\frac{1}{3}$$

I know that the function $f{(x)}=x^2$ but is there a way to calculate that function?

---

I thought maybe I do this:
$F{(x)}$ is the antiderivative of $f{(x)}$

$$\int_{a}^{b} \left(f{(x)}\right)dx=c\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$F{(b)}-F{(a)}=c\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(F{(b)}-F{(a)}\right)=\frac{d}{dx} c\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$f{(b)}-f{(a)}=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$f{(b)}=f{(a)}$$

So the question is:

Is there a way to find the function $f{(x)}$ for a given value of $a,b,c$?

$$\int_{a}^{b} \left(f{(x)}\right)dx=c$$

EDIT:

I know now that we can find an answer using:

$$\int_{a}^{b} \left(f{(x)}\right)dx=c\Longleftrightarrow f(x)=\frac{c}{b-a}$$

But is it possible to find $f(x)$ without using $a,b,c$ because in my example above we see that $f(x)=x^2$ and if I use the other method I find that $f(x)=\frac{x}{3}$

Comment: If $a,b,c$ are constants, then there are infinitely many solutions for $f$. the simplest one would a constant function, namely $f(x) = \frac{c}{b-a}$.

Comment: $a,b,c$ are given values

Comment: If you know $\int_a^b f(x) dx$ for all $a$,$b$, then you can write $f(t) = \int_a^t f(x) dx$ for some arbitrary $a$.

Comment: @Zardo, your formula seems wonky. The equation $f(t) = \int_a^t f(x) \mathrm d x$ has no solution on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: A geometrical interpretation of the question: can we say what kind of figure it is (square, triangular, disc etc) if we know that its area is $1$? As you see it does not make much sense, does it?

Comment: That example was just an example we can make it more difficult: find $f(x)$ when given that: $a=\frac{1}{2}\pi,b=\pi,c=\frac{11}{4}$

Comment: @JanEerland user251257's general formula above applies in this and all cases (at least, for $a \neq b$).

Comment: it is a constant. A constant has always a antiderivative...

Comment: Re the edit: $$\frac{d}{dx}F(b)=f(b)\ ??$$

Comment: Your derivation turns into $0 =0$, you can not infer $f(a)=f(b)$ .

Comment: The examples do not contain $a,b,c$ because they were not for general $a,b,c$ but for specific values.

Comment: @mvw is there a way to work out that my example has a solution on $f(x)=x^2$?

Comment: $\frac{n+1}{3}x^n$ would work, $\frac{1}{3(e-1)}e^x$ , etc

Comment: @mvw why does that work?

Comment: Integrating those over $[0,1]$ gives $1/3$.

Comment: in general $f$ depends on $a,b,c$. How should the integral of one function on any interval produces any number?

Comment: @user251257 Of course it has! Only one though, which is $f(x)=0$. Of course, what I meant was $f(t) = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \int_a^t f(x) \mathrm{d}x$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it is not possible, but your question is very thoughtful. Here's a fun counterexample: suppose two continuous functions $f$ and $g$ satisfy $f(1-x)=g(x)$ for all $x$, then $\int_0^1 f(x)dx=\int_0^1 g(x)dx$   (can you show this?)

To understand *intuitively* why it is not possible to solve for $f$ given $a,b,c$, interpret the integral as the area under the graph of the function. Then your question can be restated as the following geometric question: given an interval $[a,b]$ and a number $c$ is there a unique function $f$ such that the area under the graph of $f$ on the interval $[a,b]$ has area $c$? You can probably see that the answer is no. For example, if you draw the graph of a function $f$ on an interval, say $[0,1]$ and you reflect the graph of $f$ through the line $x=\frac{1}{2}$, then you get the graph of a new function $g$ that clearly has the same area as $f$ on $[0,1]$ and, as long as the graph of $f$ isn't symmetric with respect to the line $x=\frac{1}{2}$, $g$ is clearly a different function from $f$. (In this case, can you express $f$ in terms of $g$ or vice versa?)

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your question is not the difficulty of integrating certain functions or funny choices for $a,b,c$ but rather that its conditions on the solution are not specific enough to single out just one solution.

E.g. limiting the solution set to constant functions, one gets
$$
c = \int\limits_a^b \!\! f \,dx = f (b-a) \Rightarrow f = \frac{c}{b-a}
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, can you look to my edit?

Comment: Should we use \limits for \int? @mvw?

Comment: That depends on your taste and where you want to publish.

Answer (score 1):

The function is not unique. There are an infinite amount of solutions for $f$. In your example with $a= 0, b = 1, c=\frac{1}{3}$ we see that $f(x) = \frac{1}{3}$ will satisfy the equation. Thus $x^2$ and $\frac{1}{3}$ are solutions. There is not a unique function that satisfies this, there are many possible answers. Assuming $a,b,c$ are given constants we can simply use $f(x) = \frac{c}{b-a}$ as said in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Geometrically or from fundamental theorem of integral calculus your question can be restated:

Find all curves that can be drawn upon a given base, enclosed between two given parallel vertical lines and a variable top curve enclosing a given area.

If a particular solution is found, then an area can be removed from under the curve with the curve as a boundary and added elsewhere on the curve within this interval.

Clearly there is *infinitude* of such possibilities.

Comment: Note:  The area is signed

Comment: in which case it is the *net*  area being referred to.